# Installing Legacy Pack with SDL Web 8 for VBScript

Tags: web8, installation

I need to install the Legacy Pack in SDL Web 8 to support some VBScript templates.  Following the instructions on this page I ran the .exe installer at the command prompt.

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-33187D11-0B59-4ABB-A67E-C448FD952F04

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-37D4EEDC-9AFD-4AE5-ABC8-69A6DDC2109A

The problem is the Installation GUI does not show the Legacy Pack option in advanced options.  I am using the SDL Web 8.1.1 download that includes both 8.1 and 8.1.1.

Is the switch name different than the documentation?  I am using LEGACY_VISIBLE=true

I also found another list of installer switches, but the LEGACY_VISIBLE switch was not among them.  http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B9FFD1EC-A598-42C7-92BF-C24D9B21B473

Comment: The parameter is correct. I have just ran installer with using following string 'SDLWeb8CM.exe LEGACY_VISIBLE=true' and worked fine for me. Can you please check that installer log file in your %temp% folder (SDL_Web_8_timestamp.log) contains following string: Setting string variable 'LEGACY_VISIBLE' to value 'true'

Comment: Yes, this does work for me.  Maybe earlier I was not using capitals and also I was trying with the -s and then LEGACY_VISIBLE=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LEGACY_VISIBLE=true
```

is proper parameter. It worked for me when I ran installer like:

```
SDLWeb8CM.exe LEGACY_VISIBLE=true
```